# html server grizzly+jersey (.html from .jar archive)

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, grizzly

I want to serve my .html sites from a .jar archive and not from a folder.
At the moment i use grizzly (with jersey) and serve static pages like:

```
HttpServer webServer;
....
....
webServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new StaticHttpHandler("varwww"), "/app");
webServer.start();
```

Is there a way to get the webserver not to retrieve .html from folder "varwww" and to get it from myhtml.jar?

Answer (score 3):

This feature is implemented in Grizzly 2.3.3+. Here is the correspondent [issue](https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1513).

You can use special CLStaticHttpHandler and pass ClassLoader to be used to find static resources. For example:

```
httpServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(
            new CLStaticHttpHandler(new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {new URL("file:///home/username/staticfiles.jar")})), "/www");
```

Hope that will help.

Comment: could you please take a look at my grizzly question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123194/jersey-2-render-swagger-static-content-correctly-without-trailing-slash