# Serving static content with grizzly's StaticHttpHandler from within a .jar

Tags: java, jax-rs, grizzly

I want Grizzly to serve static files from within a .jar, which contains a JAX-RS application, Grizzly and all other libs. I'm using `org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler` to serve the static files.

```
public class Main {

  // ...

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    final HttpServer server = startServer();
    server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(
            new StaticHttpHandler(getTemplatePath()), "/static");
    System.in.read();
    server.stop();
  }

  private static String getTemplatePath() throws URISyntaxException {
    return Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("templates/static").getPath();
  }
}
```

But it works only, if I start the application with my IDE. If I pack a .jar and run it, the static files are not found.

Is it possible to serve static files from within a .jar with grizzly's `StaticHttpHandler`? And how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `CLStaticHttpHandler` instead of `StaticHttpHandler`.

Please take a look at this question
[html server grizzly+jersey (.html from .jar archive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806312/html-server-grizzlyjersey-html-from-jar-archive)

Comment: Thank you, but where can I find CLStaticHttpHandler? It is not in the Grizzly package and even Google finds only 3 pages about it.

Comment: It comes with Grizzly version 2.3.3. More details can be found here: https://mytecc.wordpress.com/2013/06/06/grizzly-2-3-3-serving-static-http-resources-from-jar-files/

Comment: Ok, I'm not up to date, because Grizzly is a transitive dependency from JAX-RS for me.